How to implement dependency Injection in Avalonia and register multiple views and view models?
I have built a basic Android application with .NET MAUI and I am trying now to implement the same thing with Avalonia (with MVVM Community toolkit). In MAUI the documentation clearly showed how to implement Dependency Injection. Registering the views, view-models, also services was fairly easy. In Maui I used constructor injection to inject the view model in the view as follow:
using incomeExpensTrckMAUI.ViewModels.Pages;

namespace incomeExpensTrckMAUI.Views.Pages.ExpensePages;

public partial class ExpensePageView : ContentPage
{
    public ExpensePageView(ExpensePageViewModel expensePageViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = expensePageViewModel;
    }
 }

Then in the MauiProgram.cs file, the views, view models and services were registered as in following image:

Then like that every thing worked smoothly in MAUI. Is there a similar way to implement DI in Avalonia?
Most of the tutorials are using the default Main View and Mian View Model, they show no clear way to implement DI when there are multiple views and view models. Also the documentation suggests to use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection but then when I tried the following:
using incomeExpensTrckAVALONIA.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace incomeExpensTrckAVALONIA
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static void AddCommonServices(this IServiceCollection collection)
        {
            collection.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
        }

        public static void AddExpenseServices(this IServiceCollection collection)
        {
            collection.AddSingleton<ExpensePageViewModel>();
        }   
    }
}


and:
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls.ApplicationLifetimes;
using Avalonia.Data.Core.Plugins;
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml;

using incomeExpensTrckAVALONIA.ViewModels;
using incomeExpensTrckAVALONIA.Views;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace incomeExpensTrckAVALONIA;

public partial class App : Application
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }

    public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
    {
        // Line below is needed to remove Avalonia data validation.
        // Without this line you will get duplicate validations from both Avalonia and CT
        BindingPlugins.DataValidators.RemoveAt(0);

        // Register all the services needed for the application to run
        var collection = new ServiceCollection();
        collection.AddCommonServices();

        var expenseCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        expenseCollection.AddExpenseServices();

        // Creates a ServiceProvider containing services from the provided IServiceCollection
        var services = collection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var expenseServices = expenseCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var vm = services.GetRequiredService<MainViewModel>();

        var expenseVm = expenseServices.GetRequiredService<ExpensePageViewModel>();

        if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
        {
            desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow
            {
                DataContext = vm
            };

            //desktop.MainWindow.Content = new ExpensePageView
            //{
            //    DataContext = expenseVm
            //};
        }
        else if (ApplicationLifetime is ISingleViewApplicationLifetime singleViewPlatform)
        {
            singleViewPlatform.MainView = new ExpensePageView
            {
                DataContext = expenseVm
            };
        }

        base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
    }
}


Didn't apparently work. Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Also, bare with me as this is my first time trying to work with Avalonia.

Can you provide a bit more sample code? How are you trying to display the Expense view/window?
